# How do I assault a titan with a new character in BF2142?

Tags: battlefield-2142

I've recently picked up a copy of BF2142 and I've played a few games online. I've learnt a lot by watching the other people play but one thing still alludes me. When the shield on an enemy titan fails and there is a mad rush to knock out it's reactor. I don't seem to have the equipment to knock out the shields and the subsequent control panels behind them on my own. I have seen other players (with upgraded classes?) use remote detonators, but I don't have these in any of my classes.

Is there any way for a new character to do a titan assault without the extra gear?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to single-handedly assault the Titan without the Recon's RDX charges; however you can still be effective in a group attack. Grenades can damage the consoles, as can the Engineer's anti-tank rocket. Plus you can help your team kill the defenders as any class.

If you want to excel at Titan mode, though, concentrate on Recon unlocks. Get the RDX for assaulting and/or defence, and the AP mines for defence. You might want to start with the APM; you can accumulate points rather quickly by deploying those in the Titan corridors (especially if you can convince an Engineer to drop a supply pack near you).

Answer (score 2):

For a new soldeir the first few unlocks can get you the RDX, APM and the Lambert Carbine which is more than enough to assist a squad in taking down the titan.

Remember you can also pick up a fallen soldiers kit (either allied or enemy) by pressing "G" (default) and using their weapons/utitilies. It's also a good way to "try out" kits.